# Point domain to VPS

Tags: linux, domain, vps

This is driving me crazy, since yesterday night that I am with this.. I read from everywhere but I have no success unfortunately.. 
I bought a domain on Hostinger and a VPS on ServerArc, what I what is point my new .com domain to my VPS.. what I did was this:

[image]

I've set up the DNS? (I think that they are the DNS, not sure what I did) from my VPS hosting. (1st image)

> serverarc does not offer any type of domain products or hosting, but if you have a cPanel account       with us it is very easy to point your existing domain to our servers. Go to your domain registrar (eg. GoDaddy, Namecheap, Yahoo Domains, etc.) and in the DNS settings change your nameservers to:
>   ns1.serverarc.com
>   ns2.serverarc.com
>   That's it! Easy right, now your domain will point to your serverarc cPanel hosted account.

And on child nameservers (no idea what these are) I left them blank (2nd image)

[image]

(Previously I set child nameservers to ns1.eru-mta.com, ns2.eru-mta.com, ns3.eru-mta.com and ns4.eru-mta.com; pointing to my VPS address but not sure if it was right, so I deleted them)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep using Hostinger's name servers unless you have a good reason not to (if you want to host your own name server for example); the instructions you read are only for using their shared hosting plans, and even then I'm pretty sure you can still use Hostinger's name servers by adding an A record to ServerArc's shared hosting HTTP server.

Once you changed the name servers back, add an A record pointing to the IP of your VPS, and optionally an AAAA record pointing to the IPv6 of your VPS if it has one.

Then it should be good, note that changes may take up to 48h to reflect.

Comment: Hmm I'm kinda lost.. do I need to install something on the VPS?

Comment: I've been reading some forums/tutorials but they all get me confused, some say install BIND on the VPS

Comment: Nono, what I just want is point my .com domain to my VPS so I can host a webpage there. 
In childnameservers I should put ns1.mydomain.com pointing to the VPS ip address? thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay so this is what I did: reset DNS to Hostinger default ones http://i.imgur.com/mUExtpT.png
Then on child nameservers I added ns1, ns2.. pointing to my VPS ip
http://i.imgur.com/daVwm0E.png

Comment: I have no such option on my domain panel http://i.imgur.com/9FBmHi5.png

Comment: This is getting obnoxious. Contact their technical support or look through their knowledge base. You need to **add an A record pointing to your VPS's IP**; if you can't do it then tell their techsupport to do it.